# list python; why get different results?

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
friends = ['Masum','Pavel','Sohag']
print(friends[1]) # this one gives me the result 'Pavel'

for friends in friends:
    print('Happy new yers,', friends)

print(friends[1]) # Why this one give me the result o
```

Comment: Because you've shadowed the list `friends` with the loop variable `friends` - 
you're getting `'Sohag'[0]`. Try `for friend in friends: ...` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try `friend in friends`. You kinda overwriting `friends` with same name of iterator.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
for friends in friends:
```

you **re-assign** the label `friends` to the items in this array.
After loop completion, the array does not have any name, and hence is lost. However, the label `friends` will store the last value of that array.
e.g. (`->` means '**points to**')

```
Before iteration: friends -> array
Ist iteration: friends -> 'Masum'
2nd iteration: friends -> 'Pavel'
3rd iteration and after loop completion: friends -> 'Sohag'
```

Note that there is only one variable now with value 'Sohag'. Every other variable/array is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used the name friends for the list and for the string, so your variable friends was changed from ['Masum','Pavel','Sohag'] to "Sohag" at the end of your for.

To correct this just change your for to:
        for friend in friends

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the same variable name as the list for the iteration:

```
friends = ['Masum','Pavel','Sohag']

for friend in friends:
    print('Happy new yers,', friend)

# At this point friend will be the last one while friends will still be the list you assigned
```